# Wordpress Theme + SSL doesn't work

Tags: php, css, wordpress

My personal blog works when you connect via http but not with https. When you use https it doesn't load the CSS code. Any ideas? The certification is via Let's Encrypt program.

My site:
http://nicktehpro.xyz/
Broken Link:
https://nicktehpro.xyz/

Comment: don't forget the js files as well

Comment: `href="//nicktehpro.xyz..."` is good for both http and https so you won't have to code for both. Same thing for scripts/fonts.

Comment: it's as though Wordpress will never get with the times. it's amazing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At each place in the document where u have used:

```
href="http://nicktehpro.xyz/wp-content/themes/enigma/style.css"
```

Please change it to:

```
href="wp-content/themes/enigma/style.css"
```

or use a protocol relative uri:

```
href="//nicktehpro.xyz/wp-content/themes/enigma/style.css"
```

because your references are non-secure links they are avoided when using a secure connection

Comment: Or if you want to include a fully qualified URL, leave the domain in place and use a protocol-relative URI: `href="//nicktehpro.xyz/wp-content/themes/enigma/style.css"`.

Comment: yeah even this is better. than you for your suggestion sir...

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Yeah, I had that same problem once. Gotta love solutions ;-)

Comment: @AbhishekSingh as per your edit, I see you may have seen my comment under their question ;-) that is another trick I learned some time back.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i am amazed that you faced such a small problem ever. But I have got to learn a lot from you.

Comment: anyways I am your follower now...you have an amazing experience and knowledge

Comment: @AbhishekSingh You would be surprised as to what I learn from others. The amount of rep points for members here are irrelevant to the knowledge that others have, where another may not ;-) we all learn from each other, either good or bad. and thanks, *cheers*

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though there is an error accessing the stylesheets, images, and other objects you are linking to on the page. When you go to https://nicktehpro.xyz, it is trying to load other links from http://nicktehpro.com Its not allowing you to load insecure data onto a secure page. Make sure that you are either loading all from http or https not a mixture of both. you can fix this by using relative links, starting with 
    href="/wp-content/link-to-file"
or 
    src="/wp-content/link-to-file"
instead of 
    href="http://nicktehpro.xyz/wp-content/link-to-file"

Answer (score 1):

all the links should start with https which is not the case for your css and js files , example :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://nicktehpro.xyz/wp-content/themes/enigma/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://nicktehpro.xyz/wp-content/themes/enigma/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

and the other links too

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and downloaded the theme you're using to further help you, navigate to **Header.php** and replace on

line 18 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />`

with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/enigma/style.css/" type="text/css" media="screen" />`.

**EDIT:**

After looking into it' there's also a plugin which can achieve this for you for anything that may not be working because it displays as `http` and not `https` you should consider giving it a try [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/).